# SSRS automatically creates reports from list

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2012, ssrs-subscription

We have distinct list of Party Keys (20000 approx.)
and every week we create reports for particular party keys only which has update.
Those party keys are stored in Periodic review list.

Periodic Review list = Party keys which has update

So for example 
1st week 180 party keys
2nd week 300 party keys
3rd week 30 party keys in periodic review list.

So right now I have SSRS report which has parameter named Party key and by manually entering party key it will generate report.

but I want to automate the process and would like to automatically generate reports for particular party keys which has updates and stores on share folder as PDF.

if this week they have 40 party keys in review list I want to create 40 SSRS reports for those keys.

---

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02053

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.61021.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Reporting Services   13.0.1701.8
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 13.0.1701.8

Comment: Look into data driven subscriptions

Comment: @iamdave is there any specific blog or site I can refer to?

Comment: Try [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssrs+data+driven+subscriptions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an access to the reporting database, you can easily update the subscription parameter to the new key from your list and run the job that sends that subscription. 
Basically you can have some task that takes the last Key that was processed, finds all new keys, updates the subscription, triggers the subscription job for each new key.

Here is some query I have where you can find the link between subscription and job name:

```
SELECT     
 s.subscriptionid,
 ISNULL(c_p.Name, c.Name) AS Report, 
 msdb.dbo.sysjobs.name AS SQLAgentName, 
 CASE WHEN c.Type = 4 THEN c.Name + ' [' + s.Description + ']' ELSE s.Description end AS Description, 
MAX(s.LastRunTime) AS LastRun, s.LastStatus, 
                      s.DeliveryExtension, c.Description AS HowOften, msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id, msdb.dbo.sysjobs.enabled
FROM  dbo.Catalog AS c 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Catalog AS c_p
  ON c_p.ItemID = c.LinkSourceID AND c.Type = 4
INNER JOIN dbo.Subscriptions AS s 
  ON s.Report_OID = c.ItemID 
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule 
 ON c.ItemID = dbo.ReportSchedule.ReportID 
    AND s.SubscriptionID = dbo.ReportSchedule.SubscriptionID 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
ON CAST(dbo.ReportSchedule.ScheduleID AS varchar(100)) 
   = CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobs.name AS varchar(100))
where msdb.dbo.sysjobs.enabled = 1
GROUP BY s.subscriptionid, c_p.Name, c.type, c.Name, msdb.dbo.sysjobs.name, s.Description, s.LastStatus, s.DeliveryExtension, c.Description, msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id, msdb.dbo.sysjobs.enabled
```

Modify the dbo.Subscription parameters and call 
 `exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @JobName;` 
to complete your task.